# If statements not working correctly on Laravel Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

All project works good one day ago, I cannot change any system file or something like that. But now blade if statements not working.

My blade code is

```
<html>
<body>
@if($success == "True")
            <script>
                window.parent.successPayment();
            </script>
@else

            <script>
                window.parent.failedPayment("{{$message}}");
            </script>

@endif
```

After rendering

```
<html>
<body>
        @if ($success == "True")
            <script>
                window.parent.successPayment();
            </script>
        <?php else: ?>

            <script>
                window.parent.failedPayment("<?php echo e($message); ?>");
            </script>

       <?php endif; ?>


</body>
</html>
```

If statement not rendering. I cannot solve this problem. Anyone know how can I fix this?

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF), expecting end of file (View: /var/www/vhosts/mysite.site/mysite.site/resources/views/dashboard/test.blade.php)

Comment: Try runnig `php artisan view:clear`.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using and have you checked the minimum requirements for the Laravel version you are using.

Answer (score 3):

Intresting

```
class DashboardBaseController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct(){
//        setlocale(LC_TIME, "turkish");
//        setlocale(LC_ALL,'turkish');
//
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $img = DefaultProfileImage::create($user->name, 256, "#e91e63");
...
```

If I comment **setlocale** lines code works correctly.

Comment: This is probably a laravel bug. same happened to me. And I solved the problem thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try its.

```
<html>
<body>
        @if ($success == "True")
            <script>
                window.parent.successPayment();
            </script>
         @else

            <script>
                window.parent.failedPayment("{{ e($message) }}");
            </script>

       @endif

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS ONE**

```
<html>

<body>
    <?php if ($success == "True") {?>
    <script>
        window.parent.successPayment(); 
    </script>

    <?php } else: {?>
    <script>
        window.parent.failedPayment("<?php echo e($message); ?>");   
    </script>

    <?php } endif; ?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Code is working now. setlocale is problem. I comment this lines and blade workig now